# Python - Using default values for dataframe in method

Tags: python, pandas

let's say I have the following code

```
df1 = ['a']
df2 = ['a']

def some_method():
    global df1
    global df2
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(Some populated dataframe...)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(Some populated dataframe...)

def test(my_df=df1):
    print(my_df)
```

In the following scenario, df1 outputs ['a'] when test() is called with no params. df1/df2 will print when they are passed in as params

```
some_method()
test() # Prints out ['a']
test(df1) # Works as expected
test(df2) # Works as expected
```

Can someone please explain why the default value defined in the test method does not work?

Comment: This works for me, what does `print(df1)` show? Are you somehow overwriting or shadowing `df1` in some other part of your code?

Comment: This should work in the way that you have presented it. when you execute `test()` what output do you get if any? do you get an error or nothing printed?

Comment: Can you show both how you create/operate on `df1` and `df2` before this, and what happens when you run `test()`? Namely (!), are these the actual namespaces you have, or are `df1` and `df2` defined in a separate namespace from `test()`?

Comment: ok, edited question again to be clearer. Hopefully this will help clear up some questions you have all had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is a result of three tricky Python attributes that can be hard to remember:

1. names are references to objects, but independent of the objects themselves
2. mutable and immutable objects handle chained references differently [1]
3. "the global namespace for a module is created when the module definition is read in". [2]

When `test()` is defined, `my_df` is bound to the current global object referenced by `df1`, which in your case is `['a']`. When `some_method()` is called, it changes the reference for the global name `df1` to your dataframe, but `my_df` has already been bound to the object behind the previous `df1` (`['a']`). It is not bound to the `df1` reference itself.

An illustration to simplify:

```
a = 1
b = a
a = 3
print(a)
>>> 3
print(b)
>>> 1
```

kbball suggests re-arranging, which works, because it defines `some_method()` and runs it before `test()` is defined, which means that during the `test()` definition, the global `df1` now references the dataframe. As before, `my_df=df1` points to the object behind the `df1` reference, but now that has changed to the dataframe, so `test()` will print that.

To see this in action, use your current code as posted but add to your test:

```
print(df1) # will print out ['a']
some_method() # changes object references of global names df1, df2
print(df1) # will print out dataframe
test() # Prints out ['a']
test(df1) # Works as expected
test(df2) # Works as expected
```

Your solution then is to re-arrange your code to define `test()` after `some_method()` is called (you don't need the return that kbball includes), or, you can ensure that `df1` within test refers to the current global name `df1` each time it runs:

```
def test(my_df=None):
    global df1
    if not my_df:
        my_df = df1
    print(my_df)

df1 = ['a']
test() # returns ['a']
some_method()
test() # returns dataframe
```

I know that's a long explanation, but I hope it clears it up for you. It's a wonky issue.

[1] https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/

[2] https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I didn't realize that it bound it to the variables definition at the time of creation. I was kinda assuming it did your if clause under the hood :(

Comment: Sure! I just discovered that your exact problem and related issues are described exactly under point 4.7 of the [Control Flow docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions), in case you are interested. You hit a fairly obscure error, so no wonder it was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do some re-arranging:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = ['a']

def some_method():
  global df1
  df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
  return df1

some_method()

def test(my_df=df1):
    print(my_df)

test()

#output

    A   B   C   D
0  95  83  33  92
1  22  68  87  99
2  61  37  11  51
3  18  76  77  47
4   1   9  38  21
5  27  87  75  56
6  55  95  62  98
7  78  49  93  48
8  83  54  40  23
9   2  82   3  57
```

Comment: Sorry I was trying to do bare-minimum code. Please see updated question

Comment: I'm not sure that changing the ordering would solve the issue. If I place the test() call before the return statement in some_method() I still get ['a']

Comment: He's sort of right, but this is not a great solution. I am writing out an explanation currently.

Comment: Also (still a newbie) I assume that all defs can go safely to the top of the file since they don't get executed until called. Is that correct?